# Kafka leader election Zookeeper failure

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, leader-election

The controller elects a new leader from the ISR for a partition when the current one dies. My understanding is that this data is persisted in Zookeeper. What happens when a Zookeeper node dies during this write? Can this mean that some brokers might still different leader for the newly-leader-elected partition?

I tried digging around the docs but could not find anything satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding is that this data is persisted in Zookeeper

Yes, This ISR set is persisted to ZooKeeper whenever it changes. ([Reference](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_replicatedlog))

> What happens when a Zookeeper node dies during this write?

Zookeeper works on quorum and it means majority of servers from the cluster. (See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51835572/2534090)) (snippet below)

1. With a 3 node cluster, the majority is 2 nodes. So you can tolerate
   only 1 node not being  in sync at the same time.
2. With a 5 node cluster, the majority is 3 nodes. So you can tolerate
   only 2 nodes not being in sync at the same time.

So long as there is majority, the decision is made and so the leader election will continue.